# How can I insert a array of objects into a mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem where I have an array of objects like this:

```js
 [
  {
    department_id: '6256f8ae6f749617e8167416',
    employee_id: '6253ca0c6f749618a8d022af',
    employee_number: '1234'
  },
  {
    department_id: '6256f8ae6f749617e8167416',
    employee_id_id: '6253ca0c6f749618a8d022af',
    employee_number: '1503'
  }
]
```

and would like to use node js and mysql to insert it into a database so I have got this script

```js
Department.assignEmployeetoDepartment = (employees, result) => {
  let employees_array = Object.values(rooms);

  db.query(
    `INSERT INTO department_employee (department_id, employee_id, employee_number) VALUES ?`,
    [employees_array],
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }

      console.log("success: ", res);
      result(null, res);
    }
  );
};
```

when I use the code above, I get

```sql
INSERT INTO department_employee (department_id, employee_id, employee_number) VALUES '[object Object]', '[object Object]'
```

which does not work for obvious reasons.
I tried to stringify the object
and I also tried to use a for loop to iterate over the employees array and it did not work as it says the headers were already sent.

How could I store the array (which can vary in length into the database?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to loop over your array and then you can insert for every array element one row into your database

Answer (score 1):

As per mysql- [Escaping query values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values)

> Nested arrays are turned into grouped lists (for bulk inserts), e.g. [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] turns into ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')

You probably want to map the values to array, you can't pass array of JSON object to query

```
  db.query(
    `INSERT INTO department_employee (department_id, employee_id, employee_number) VALUES ?`,
    [employees_array.map(employee => [employee.department_id, employee.employee_id, employee.employee_number])],
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }

      console.log("success: ", res);
      result(null, res);
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm suggesting for you will serve you safe if you make your data an array of arrays;

```
const employeesData = [
     [
      '6256f8ae6f749617e8167416',
      '6253ca0c6f749618a8d022af',
      '1234'
    ],
    [
     '6256f8ae6f749617e8167416',
     '6253ca0c6f749618a8d022af',
     '1503'
    ],
  ];
```

Next, prepare your query like this;

```
const sql = `INSERT INTO images (department_id, employee_id, employee_number) VALUES?`;
```

You're now ready to run your query liike below;

```
    db
  .query(sql, [employeesData])
  .then(rows => {
     res.status(200).json({
       status: "success",
       message:"Data inserted successfully"
     });
   })
   .catch(err => {
     res.status(500).json({
       status: "error",
       error: err.message
     });
  });
```

You can generate array of values to insert using array's map method like shown below,

```
employeesData = dataSourceArray.map ( (data) => {
  return [
     department_id,
     employee_id,
     employee_number
];
});
```